# Board layout for a blinker circuit

Tags: layout, board

I am designing a [blinker circuit](http://4.imimg.com/data4/ID/AD/MY-920798/solar-powered-blinker-250x250.jpg) in Eagle. These blinkers are used at roadside for indication purpose. These blinkers contain two PCBs. One is PCB contains 555 timer circuit which generate timing. Another PCB contains all the leds. I will be using 12v. I have connected 4 leds in series to make a string and then using 25-26 strings in parallel. I have designed the schematic. But need some help regarding board layout.

As these PCB needs to be in circular shape, so for that I have drawn circles in board layout and planning to put leds on them. Is this the correct way of designing board layout for such kind of PCBs. I also need to put every led at an equal distance to make a proper PCB. Does any one has any experience in designing board layout for these PCBs. Any help or any link would be very useful to me.

Following is the way I am doing it.:

[image]

I have drawn circles and putting leds over them. After routing, I will delete the circles and the circuit will be in the proper shape. This is all I can think about designing this circuit. And for the equal distance between leds, I am not using any measuring technique, just putting them with random guess.

Comment: For KiCad fans: I have checked if KiCad has a tool for this and yes; you just right click the footprint, click duplicate and select circular array and you are done..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a circular placement ULP, e.g. http://irq5.io/2013/03/30/circular-layout-ulp-for-eagle/ If you really want to have it *perfect* change the angle of the LEDs to non 90° rotation.

No circular routing ULP, sorry.

Comment: This ULP looks interesting. I'll definitely try it.